# Initializers for a custom-made button

Tags: ios, swift

```
class BorderedButton: UIButton {

   // Some properties

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.themeBorderedButton()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.themeBorderedButton()
    }

    func themeBorderedButton() {
         //sets up the button
    }

}
```

I have been reading a bit of code for my project and I came across this. I have read through Swift 2.0's initializer documentations, I understand that for the `override init` we are simply overriding the init from `UIView` and this initializer is called when we create the button programmatically. The `required init` called when we create a button in the Storyboard.

**My 1st question is:**

Where exactly in the code is this `required init` specified because I looked at all the superclasses of NSCoder and there isn't a method that has a `required init`

**My 2nd question is:**

What exactly does the NSCoder do I've read the documentation and I have a rough understanding that it transfers information, but do I need to know anything beyond that? In a non-trivial application does the class `NSCoder` get used a lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol which requires `init(coder:)`.

`UIKit` uses `NSCoder` to load views, view hierarchies and view controllers defined in storyboards and XIB files.

`NSCoder` is a scheme to store and load structured data in iOS. It's mostly used through `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

I don't recommend to use it anywhere except for the case mentioned above, esp. since maintaining backward comaptilbity became harder with Swift.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the backwards compatibility part?

Comment: `NSCoder` stores class names when serializing objects. When loading the data again it looks for these classes by name. In Swift renaming a class, moving a class, renaming a module, changing the class visibility, changing class annotations and even renaming the file a class is located in can all cause it's internal class name to change. Even just updating to a new Swift release can cause the name to change. Although you can tell `NSCoder` about the changed class names it's a tedious work and you'll collect a large number of cryptic class names over time as your app keeps growing.

Comment: Also `NSCoder` needs a lot of handling to avoid it from crashing any time it sees a value of an unexpected type. We actually released an app update which kept crashing for most users on app start. We noticed that only after the release because these users had very old data with slightly different class names which we didn't notice during testing. It's difficult to keep track of these changes.